# duplicate truecrypt drive

Tags: 12.04, backup, ext4, truecrypt

How would I go about duplicating a truecrypt hard drive for redundancy purposes?

I have lots of original video content, which I store on encrypted drives.  And wanted to know the best way to create truecrypt backups

Comment: Just `dd` the partition or copy the Truecrypt container. They don't depend on any weird drive-related stuff, but you'll want to have the keyfiles around.

Comment: What is ` dd `?

Comment: `dd` is used to make direct copies of hard disks or partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know what disk they are: 
`dd if=/dev/input partition of=/dev/output partition`

Find the disk names in **Disk Utility**.